# Drop duplicate from 2 dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've 2 dataframes, `df1` and `df2`, with an `emails` column (and other non important ones.)

I want to drop rows in `df2` that contain emails that are already in `df1`.

How can I do that?

Comment: this is isin problem . df2[~df2.email.isin(df1.email)]

Comment: @W-B isin worked, you rock

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
df_1[~df_1['email_column'].isin(df_2['email_column'].tolist())
```